# Scraping reviews with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am using Pycharm and it's giving error

```
:selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <a
```

I am trying to take out the Safety reviews by going to the href link in the `class="quote"`

[image: Error]"

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import re
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\tanmay\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g304551-d299120-Reviews-or10-The_Lalit_New_Delhi-New_Delhi_National_Capital_Territory_of_Delhi.html")

print("Name :",driver.find_element_by_id("HEADING").text)

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='TABS_REVIEWS']/span").click()
Element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("query_elem")
Element.send_keys("Safety")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.ui_icon.search.search-icon').click()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,2050);")
driver.implicitly_wait(0.1)
time.sleep(0.1)

div = driver.find_element_by_class_name("quote")
div.find_element_by_css_selector('a').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome("#path")
driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g304551-d299120-Reviews-or10-The_Lalit_New_Delhi-New_Delhi_National_Capital_Territory_of_Delhi.html")

driver.find_element_by_class_name("query_elem").clear()
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_class_name("query_elem")
search_bar.send_keys('Safety')
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# Below are the hrefs.
for div in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('quote'):
    a = div.find_element_by_class_name('title')
    print(a.get_attribute('href'))

# Click on the nav for next page
# go to next page
next_page = driver.find_element_by_class_name('next')
next_page.click()
```

Comment: don't use time.sleep()